# Searchbar with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently trying to combine [MUI autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) with [MUI searchbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-search-bar), to get a Searchbar that can give me suggestions. I have tried the following:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cthpv

```
import React from "react";
import useAutocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/useAutocomplete";
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";

export default function UseAutocomplete() {
  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    options: [
      { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
      { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 }
    ],
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <label {...getInputLabelProps()}>useAutocomplete</label>
        <SearchBar {...getInputProps()} />
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
      </div>
      {groupedOptions.length > 0 ? (
        <ul {...getListboxProps()}>
          {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
            <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>{option.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and also

https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-hill-9c5jh?file=/demo.js:0-630

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";

const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];

export default function CustomInputAutocomplete() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="custom-input-demo"
      options={options}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
          <SearchBar
            style={{ width: 200 }}
            type="text"
            {...params.inputProps}
          />
          <input style={{ width: 200 }} type="text" {...params.inputProps} />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

However, with both, when I try using type in my searchbar, I get `inputRef.current.removeAttribute is not a function`. It appears to me as if the error was that the Searchbar is not forwarding the correct props to the Input component? Is there a way I can fix this without recreating [MUI searchbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-search-bar) myself, or do I have to create my own searchbar?

Comment: why dont you instead use https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ ?

Answer (score -1):

type this in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Autocomplete Search Box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="search-input">
        <a href="" target="_blank" hidden></a>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type to search..">
        <div class="autocom-box">
          <!-- here list are inserted from javascript -->
        </div>
        <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/suggestions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

and type this in css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #644bff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #664AFF;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.wrapper .search-input{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.search-input input{
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 60px 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.search-input.active input{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.search-input .autocom-box{
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box{
  padding: 10px 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.autocom-box li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box li{
  display: block;
}
.autocom-box li:hover{
  background: #efefef;
}

.search-input .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #644bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and this script.js

```
// getting all required elements
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-input");
const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
const icon = searchWrapper.querySelector(".icon");
let linkTag = searchWrapper.querySelector("a");
let webLink;

// if user press any key and release
inputBox.onkeyup = (e)=>{
    let userData = e.target.value; //user enetered data
    let emptyArray = [];
    if(userData){
        icon.onclick = ()=>{
            webLink = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + userData;
            linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
            console.log(webLink);
            linkTag.click();
        }
        emptyArray = suggestions.filter((data)=>{
            //filtering array value and user characters to lowercase and return only those words which are start with user enetered chars
            return data.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase()); 
        });
        emptyArray = emptyArray.map((data)=>{
            // passing return data inside li tag
            return data = '<li>'+ data +'</li>';
        });
        searchWrapper.classList.add("active"); //show autocomplete box
        showSuggestions(emptyArray);
        let allList = suggBox.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (let i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
            //adding onclick attribute in all li tag
            allList[i].setAttribute("onclick", "select(this)");
        }
    }else{
        searchWrapper.classList.remove("active"); //hide autocomplete box
    }
}

function select(element){
    let selectData = element.textContent;
    inputBox.value = selectData;
    icon.onclick = ()=>{
        webLink = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + selectData;
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
        linkTag.click();
    }
    searchWrapper.classList.remove("active");
}

function showSuggestions(list){
    let listData;
    if(!list.length){
        userValue = inputBox.value;
        listData = '<li>'+ userValue +'</li>';
    }else{
        listData = list.join('');
    }
    suggBox.innerHTML = listData;
}
```

and this suggestion.js

```
let suggestions = [
    "Channel",
    "CodingLab",
    "CodingNepal",
    "YouTube",
    "YouTuber",
    "YouTube Channel",
    "Blogger",
    "Bollywood",
    "Vlogger",
    "Vechiles",
    "Facebook",
    "Freelancer",
    "Facebook Page",
    "Designer",
    "Developer",
    "Web Designer",
    "Web Developer",
    "Login Form in HTML & CSS",
    "How to learn HTML & CSS",
    "How to learn JavaScript",
    "How to became Freelancer",
    "How to became Web Designer",
    "How to start Gaming Channel",
    "How to start YouTube Channel",
    "What does HTML stands for?",
    "What does CSS stands for?",
];
```

hopefully you like it if you need full code here's link >>> https://www.codingnepalweb.com/p/download-timer-autocomplete-search.html